# Can not get shared preference with GSON

Tags: android, gson, sharedpreferences

i have a bunch of Maps and Arrays saved in a SharedPreference. However one Map called algorithms_tmp throws an error called:

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 9 path $.
```

The other ArrayList and HashMap is correctly processed. Here is the code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("OverViewPref", MODE_PRIVATE);

String pref_algorithms = prefs.getString("algorithms","");
String pref_algorithmNames = prefs.getString("algorithmNames","");
String pref_algorithm_information = prefs.getString("algorithm_information","");

Type type_algorithms = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>>(){}.getType();
Type type_algorithmNames = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>(){}.getType();
Type type_algorithm_information = new TypeToken<HashMap<String,String>>(){}.getType();

boolean bool_algorithms= prefs.contains("algorithms");
boolean bool_algorithmsNames=prefs.contains("algorithmNames");
boolean bool_algorithm_information=prefs.contains("algorithm_information");


if(bool_algorithms && bool_algorithmsNames && bool_algorithm_information){
    HashMap<String,HashMap<String,HashSet<String>>> algorithms_tmp= gson.fromJson(pref_algorithms, type_algorithms);
    HashMap<String,String> algorithm_information_tmp= gson.fromJson(pref_algorithm_information, type_algorithm_information);
    ArrayList<String> algorithmNames_tmp= gson.fromJson(pref_algorithmNames, type_algorithmNames);

    algorithms.putAll(algorithms_tmp);
    algorithmNames.addAll(algorithmNames_tmp);
    algorithm_information.putAll(algorithm_information_tmp);
}
```

The Error is thrown at the following code-line:

```
HashMap<String,HashMap<String,HashSet<String>>> algorithms_tmp= gson.fromJson(pref_algorithms, type_algorithms);
```

Google did not help me concerning my problem. What am i doing wrong here?

UPDATE:

The structures saved to the 'prevs' are the same as mentioned in the if-clause. Precisely said, the structure of "algorithms pref" which makes problems here is saved as follows:

```
 {  
   "CPM":{  
      "Cluster8":[  
         "115",
         "262",
         "312",
         "220"
      ], ...
   },
   "Infomap":{  
      "Cluster5":[  
         "273",
         "152",
         "78",
         "4",
         "275",
         "195",
         "218",
         "181",
         "306",
         "328"
      ], ...
   }, ...
}
```

UPDATE II:

I saved the HashMap "algorithms" as a file and checked if it is in proper JSON format. And the result was yes. So my data is parsed correctly.

Comment: we'd need to see the structures you're saving to the prefs

Comment: I added the structure how "algorithms" is saved. As I print the preference it is outputted correctly. However the conversion failes everytime at that point mentioned before

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. The TypeToken of `type_algorithms` was wrong. It had to be the type:

```
HashMap<String,HashMap<String,HashSet<String>>>
```